# EXISTS number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE *condition*)
```

Can I check if there are, for example, 3 rows respecting the table2 condition?
So something like

```
[...]WHERE EXISTS 3 (SELECT[...]
```

Thanks

Comment: try this, **SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE EXISTS (SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE condition);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question to Gordon's answer, you want to select records the ID of which occurs three times as an AssociatedID. So select all AssociatedIDs that occur thrice and then select all records with an ID n that data set.

```
select *
from mytable 
where id in (select associatedid from mytable group by associatedid having count(*) = 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

You would do this with something other than `exists`.  For instance, aggregate `table2` and count the rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     (SELECT t2.??
      FROM table2 t2
      WHERE conditions (no correlation conditions)
      GROUP BY t2.??
      HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
     ) t2
     ON t1.?? = t2.??;
```

Comment: Can I join the same table?
I have Table1 with columns: "ID" and "AssociatedID". I have to search rows, in Table1, where there are 3 "AssociatedID" corresponding to "ID", and print the row with this "ID".

Comment: @doej . . . Yes, you can join to the same table.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply count:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE *condition*) = 3;
```

Comment: I have to select rows where "ID" appears 3 times in "AssociatedID" (in other rows), in the same table. Is this correct? `SELECT * FROM table1 A WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 B WHERE A.ID=B.AssociatedID) = 3;`

Comment: Yes. But I prefer my other answer anyway :-) But that's personal preference. I just like the idea of getting the IDs I am interested in first and only then select the records that match those IDs. But as you say "in other rows" ... can it happen that a record has the same value in ID and AssociatedID? Then you'd have to excluse these.